# Boarder Thickness value

Tags: css, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

When we say Boarder thickness ="1" for WPF XAML Control, what is 1? Is it Pixel or Points or Inches? How Can I convert it to pixels?

I been Following MSDN but it says Thickness class constructor accepts parameter "uniformLength", but that doesn't say what is it.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Please view Thickness Properties [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.thickness(v=vs.110).aspx). For every side there is description "Gets or sets the width, in pixels"

Comment: Thank you! I have a situation where I am setting BoarderThickness to 0.8 and its working in WPF but how can you divide pixel?

Comment: At the same page, there is Pixel description: "px (default) is device-independent units (1/96th inch per unit)". So, I believe that if your screen resolution allows to show points less that 1/96 inch, WPF's pixel can be divided

Comment: Thank you so much, now it makes much more sense! thank a lot.